# Adding a condition in recursive function to read out specific key and its value inside a nested json file

Tags: python, json, if-statement, recursion, nested

I have been working on a project on the in which I am trying to get a blockdevice inside a server that acts as a backup disk and has to be replaced every week atleast once.

.json file that shows whats mounted inside the server: https://pastebin.com/hmjv81nS

I have some code that includes a recursive function to list out the names and the sizes of the disks inside the server:

```
import json

with open('path to json file') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

def process_data(data_list, names, sizes):
    for d in data_list:
        names.append(d['name'])
        sizes.append(d['size'])
        if 'children' in d:
            process_data(d['children'],  names, sizes)
    return names, sizes
    
print(process_data(data['blockdevices'], [], []))
>>> (['sda', 'sda1', 'md0', 'sda2', 'sda5', 'md1', 'sda6', 'md2', 'sda7', 'md3', 'sdb', 'sdb1', 'md0', 'sdb2', 'sdb5', 'md1', 'sdb6', 'md2', 'sdb7', 'md3', 'sdc', 'sdc1', 'DATA', 'sdd', 'sdd1', 'DATA2', 'sde', 'sde1'], ['931,5G', '18,6G', '18,6G', '1K', '9,3G', '9,3G', '18,6G', '18,6G', '885G', '884,8G', '931,5G', '18,6G', '18,6G', '1K', '9,3G', '9,3G', '18,6G', '18,6G', '885G', '884,8G', '5,5T', '5,5T', '5,5T', '3,7T', '3,7T', '3,7T', '9,1T', '9,1T'])
```

Now I want to add a condition to find out which of the disks is the backup disk.
I know for a fact that the backup disk is >5.0T in size, that there is only ONE another dict under the list of key "children" and inside the second dict there is not another "children" that lists another dict.

My approach was to find out inside the function that if there is 2 children inside the list of the disk then the disk will be ignored and not printed out.

The result should be a print of disk "sde" hence it has only a single dict under its list "children" and not another "children" inside that dict.

Hope you understand my concern it has been a struggle to find out a way.

Comment: the condition to ignore the disk might be `if not ('children' in d and 'children' not in d['children'])`, or something similar?

Comment: How do I implement it? Do i replace it with `if 'children' in d:`?

Comment: I tried `def process_data(data_list, names, sizes):
    for d in data_list:
        names.append(d['name'])
        sizes.append(d['size'])
        if not ('children' in d and 'children' not in d['children']):
            names.remove(d['name'])
            sizes.remove(d['size'])
        else:
            process_data(d['children'],  names, sizes)
 
    return names, sizes` but yea not luck

Comment: You don't need `.remove`. Just don't `.append` the things that you don't want to append.

Comment: So just `if not ('children' in d and 'children' not in d['children']):
            process_data(d['children'],  names, sizes)` ?

Comment: cant seem to just pick out "sde" and remove "sda" "sdb" ect. on print. It keeps printing out `(['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd', 'sde'], ['931,5G', '931,5G', '5,5T', '3,7T', '9,1T'])`. I am confused as hell :/

Comment: `if not ('children' in d and 'children' not in d['children']): names.append(d['name'])
        sizes.append(d['size'])` then `if 'children' in d:
            process_data(d['children'],  names, sizes)`

Comment: To be fair, I am not completely sure I correctly understand the desired behaviour you want, so I'm only guessing. It would be easier if you provided a much shorter example (with only "name" and "children", and less than 5 elements) so it would be easier to understand your explanation of which elements you want to keep and which you don't want to keep.

Comment: Here I have created a simplefied .json so its easier to read and understand: https://pastebin.com/791C56J8 . Basically I want to ignore the whole dict "sda"  because it has a second `'children'`. The condition in mind was to print the dict (`"name": "sdb"` and the `"size": "9.1T"`) when there is no other key called children inside an existing children.

Comment: Then I think this should work: https://pastebin.com/naPz6fwH

Comment: Tried the exact same approach but the result gives me just two empty lists. https://pastebin.com/atY9Ab1C

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There was a `not` that should not be there. https://pastebin.com/tT4ecj9W

Comment: edit I got it I forgot to set `names = d['name']` and `sizes = d['size']` god I am stupid. https://pastebin.com/02FdbyPy

Comment: Finding a bug always feels like that :) Debugging code that we wrote ourselves can be harder than someone else's code, because we know what we wanted to write, and when we read what we wrote, we misread it and interpret it as what we wanted rather than what it is.

Comment: yea exactly having a hard time with a simple solution sometime can be frustrating but the moment its debugged is a great one :)

Comment: Nevermind back to square one it seems to still not work accordingly. I tested it out with a different arranged .json file (simplefied version: https://pastebin.com/2TYCsuGB) and it just keeps on printing out only "sde" despite it not meeting the condition (https://pastebin.com/8gaVy7wY). Result should be "sdc".

Comment: Why did you add `names = d['name']` and `sizes = d['size']`? Writing this will completely discard the previous values of `names` and `sizes`, effectively erasing the work that has been done by previous iterations of the loop and previous recursive calls. This is why I only ever used `names.append(...)` and never `names = ...`.

Comment: Tested out things and it appeared to give me sde in the first version. Now I used: https://pastebin.com/6ErSjtDA. But yea nothing going on there.

Comment: So I didnt come to a solution at all. Might need help again. I was thinking about if there is something possibly missing within the loop.

Comment: So for starters again: I am trying to get THE key ("name", "sizes") inside the first layer with the condition that it has no second children and print it out. I use this JSON file for simple starters: https://pastebin.com/791C56J8. So far we got this code together: https://pastebin.com/wTxCT04H. I found out that there is a step missing but I cant figure out how I fix it and I cant find anything. Somehow noone tried to create a condition to find a specific single key ever on the internet. My buddies also cant find a solution.

Comment: I think the main difficulty we have is communication? I've probably misunderstood what you wanted precisely. Note that stackoverflow isn't really well-suited for a back-and-forth discussion like that.

Comment: Yea I figured but I found the solution now for real: https://pastebin.com/qfGGVCKT . I thought about if I am looping deep enough and it was true that I wasnt. So I just went down a layer and it works now. Also works with different .json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself with big help from Stef.
Using a simplified version:

```
data= {
         "blockdevices": [
            {"name": "sda", "size": "3,7T",
               "children": [
                  {"name": "sdd1", "size": "3,7T",
                     "children": [
                        {"name": "DATA2", "size": "3,7T"}
                     ]
                  },
                  {"name": "sdd2", "size": "1K"}
               ]
            },
            {"name": "sdb", "size": "9,1T",
               "children": [
                  {"name": "sde1", "size": "9,1T"}
               ]
            }
         ]
      }

def process_data(data_list, names, sizes):
    for d in data_list:
            c = d['children']
            for child in c:
                    if 'children' not in c[0]:
                        names.append(d['name'])
                        sizes.append(d['size'])
                        if 'children' in c[0]:
                            process_data(c['children'], [], [])

    return names, sizes

print('Disk:', process_data(data['blockdevices'], [], []), 'is backup disk.')

>>> Disk: (['sdb'], ['9,1T']) is backup disk.
```

Originally I didnt loop deep enough in the nested tree structure so it printed nothing.